# How to change bootstrap columns reponsive layout with php?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new to php and wordpress and need help. I'm trying to change my bootstrap responsive grid with php. >992px I should have 3 columns, >768px I should have only 2 columns and <767px I should have only one. How can I do this with php? Really appreciate the help.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="row">

    <?php $i = 1; while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="cover-card">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'image img-responsive')); ?>

            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="text">
                  <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
                  <?php the_content(); ?>
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Comprar</a>
                </div> <!-- /.text -->
            </div> <!-- /.overlay -->
        </div> <!-- /.cover-card -->
    </div> <!-- /.col-md-4 -->

<?php if ( $i % 3 === 0 ) { echo '</div> <!-- /.row -->

<div class="row">'; } ?>
<!-- store item -->
<?php $i++; endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div>
```

This is what happens with my loop on the sm resolution: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"></div>
```

The grid system is based off the idea that there are 12 columns. In the documentation it will describe what width pertains to the xs, sm, md, and lg classes.

The above solution should work because it will place three cards per row if the display is greater than 992px, two if greater than 768px, and one if less.

Here's [a little example](http://codepen.io/adamhari25/pen/VpqRpo)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although this is not working. I have edited my question with an image that can explain better.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Check my example that I editted in for more guidance. The row should be nested in a container div as well. If it's still not working it ought to be WP interfering